# How can I delete my account?

Tags: discussion, account

I'm struggling trying to delete my serverfault account.

I've managed to delete my other accounts like meta stack exchange or superuser.

I've been filling the form to delete account many times but never received any email like I did for superuser or meta stack exchange.

What's wrong with serverfault account deletion?

Any mod can help?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8):

I'm a bit behind on emails. Fortunately, I have 8 of them from you, so there's a *really* good chance I'd have gotten to it eventually.

But since you posted here, I've gone ahead and just scheduled your account for deletion. It'll be deleted in the next 24-48 hours (it's a weekend here, no promises on keeping to an exact schedule):

[image]

Comment: "Fortunately, I have 8 of them from you, so there's a *really* good chance I'd have gotten to it eventually."  ROTFL!

Answer (score 3):

You have posted on Serverfault, so you have to use the [contact form](https://serverfault.com/contact) to ask the admin team to delete the account. This can't be done by mods.  If you have already done that, please leave a comment so we can try to ask the team to look into this.

See https://serverfault.com/help/deleting-account

Comment: I've used the contact form many times. I never received any email (but it worked and I received email for sister sites like superuser).

Comment: OK, I'll try to get ahold of the team. Just out of curiosity, may I ask why you want to delete this and your other accounts?

Comment: Because I don't use them anymore. Therefore, I want them to be deleted.

Comment: @coincoin Well, the contributions you gave might be worth to be retained for future readers...

Comment: @glglgl: Deletion of a user doesn't delete his answers. They will be anonymized but stay put. After all, you put all the stuff you write here into the Creative Commons, so there is no need to delete anything.